# Searching a process' memory on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

How can I search the memory state of an process in Linux? Specifically I wish to identify certain regions of interest, and peek at them at regular intervals, possibly occasionally poking new values.

I suspect an answer may involve calls to [ptrace()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), and reading [/proc/[pid]/mem](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html), but need more to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed some code for the requested functionality.

The module [memutil](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/tibia/butox/memutil.py) provides process memory region iteration, and python or C memory reading with assistance from the [ptrace](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/tibia/butox/ptrace.py) module, and [readmem](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/tibia/butox/cutil/readmem.c) executable.

If there is any questions, or requests for standalone tools, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can achieve what you want by parsing `/proc/[pid]/maps` -- I've used that to diagnose invalid pointers

Comment: I'd like a little more info, and a demo :P

Comment: I just skimmed through Valgrind's `aspacemgr-linux.c` which reads `/proc/self/maps` -- not easy to follow but maybe you can grab information from there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using GDB would be an option? You should be able to do things like periodically reading memory using breakpoints.